Which pipe route is better for my sink relocation?
I am relocating my sink from a back wall to a window.  Due to space constrains, I want to avoid altering the plumbing below the ground level (though I have a basement).  I have proposed two pipe routes in the attached picture (red and yellow) with a blue arrow pointing at the wall against which the sink will be placed (the center of the sink is aligned with the center of a window, just out of frame).  I plan on using 2" PVC.  Jurisdiction is Dayton, OH.

The red line T's off the main line (using the appropriate direction of sanitary-tee) at the top and the bottom for the drain and vent respectively, each branch of which runs horizontally inside the wall to where the pipe comes out, join vertically together with another tee branching off to run along the back wall (not inside, it's an external wall) to the sink drain.  The advantage of this, in my mind, is that it's considerably easier to get the slope right - the disadvantage is that I need to drill 4 holes and run two lines inside the wall, and I think it would be harder to snake if something went wrong - not sure on ideal cleanout placement (though I think it's less likely for something to go wrong since it's more robust).
The yellow line just t's off at the right height (accounting for slope) from the main line, runs horizontally through the wall, elbows, and runs horizontally to the sink.  Very straightforward, and likely easier to snake from the sink's P-trap.  Also potentially more difficult to install correctly - I don't think I have a lot of slack with the 1/4"-per-foot slope (4-foot run along the back wall, and ~32" of run inside the current wall - 6 and 2/3' of the hypothetical maximum 8' on a 2" pipe), so potentially more likely to run into an issue?
Can anybody verify my analysis and add personal experience?  Is one of these options clearly better?  Are there things I have not considered?  Is there an alternate route that would be more optimal still?

You have correctly identified the two options and the pros and cons of both. The only thing to add is that your local code may limit the cumulative change in the direction of the trap arm.
My local code limits it to 135°. So I would use two 45° elbows to make the first change in direction and then use one more 45° entering the cabinet at a 45° angle. I would then use the joint in the p-trap to square up the run:

